# request closed after piping to proxy (node.js v16)

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, request

I have a simple proxy server as below:

```js
const http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log('serve: ' + request.url);

  const options = {
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: request.url,
    method: 'GET'
  };

 
  let proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.pipe(response);
  });

  request.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Request Closed');
    proxy.destroy();
  });

  request.pipe(proxy);
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

I added a `close` listener on the `request` event, so I could destroy the proxy if the request connection is closed. The main problem is the `close` event fired earlier than expected and I got the following error:

```
Request Closed
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:420:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at ClientRequest.onerror (node:internal/streams/readable:773:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:420:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

This becomes weird because everything works fine on node.js v14/v12.

P.S: I know there is a way in which I can solve the problem by changing `request` to `response` for the `close` listener, but I'm looking for the reason.

Comment: Isn't this expected behavior? Once the client has sent the request the stream should end. The close event on response tells you if the client terminated the connection (possibly prematurely)